# How do I redirect to another php file while passing along $_FILES?

Tags: php, file, redirect

Ok, so I have a php api on one server used for uploading images, and I want it to redirect to another server while passing along the $_FILES data. I tried using the header() method, but it seems $_FILES gets lost in the process. What would be the most straightforward solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best idea would be to

- save image
- send request to another server with link to current image
- get image from target server
- proccess image on target server
- delete image from source server

It's nothing hard.

Comment: As alternative, instead of sending a link, we can send CURL request with file. In case when accepting server can not be changed. But sending a link is easier.

Comment: I was thinking of trying CURL. How would it for files?

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect using existing POST (or FILES) data, only GET (the URL query string).

You can either save that data in session / disk / DB and reference it via a GET parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the $_FILES array, and pass it as a URL argument. But it wouldn't do you much good. The actual uploaded file's contents aren't included in this array; just the name and some metadata. Plus the file will be deleted at the end of the original script.